# Parameterised load in Azure Mapping Data Flows

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a Data Warehouse load using Azure Data Factory and Mapping data flows. I have run into an issue when I am trying to sink my data. I am using the following Mapping Data Flow

[image: Full Mapping Data Flow]

[image: Select RowsToInsert]
My problem initially is with the Select tas. Since the parameter columns are being loaded from a config table I need this task to only select two columns from the list and insert into my target table. The first is the ID of the table and the second is a column called `hashKey` that is created in the Derived Calculation tab.

I get the following error when I try: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand your intent ... You're looking to parameterized the target ID column name in your destination database?

Comment: Hi Mark, that is correct. I want to parameterise the Target ID column in my destination

Comment: @Sarath Per my experience and knowledge about Data Factory, we can not do that.

Comment: I would add one more requirement for my ETL, I need to limit the number of rows being delivered to a table. For example, I need to load only ID columns to my HUB table and attribute information to SAT tables

Comment: You're on the right path. Use the Select transformation with a rule-based matching pattern. You can probably simplify your matching rule to just: name == 'ID'.

If that still gives you an error, then submit a ticket on Azure, that might be a bug.

Just make sure you delete that bottom empty blank rule from your Select mapping first.

Comment: @Sarath Could you share the workaround as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my problem I was having around creating a meta-data driven column names in my pipeline. The error message I was seeing before was user error.

I resolved my error by creating a rule-based mapping. An example of my solution is below.

A few things to note:

"name " in the image below is the name of column in the pipeline
the items in on the right-hand side are used to rename target columns

[image: Metadata Driven rename]